# "On" vs. "Off of" vs. "Off"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, prepositions

Which of the following is grammatically correct?

> He needs to call off his dogs on her.
>
> He needs to call his dogs off of her.
>
> He needs to call his dogs off her.

Comment: They all seem grammatically correct, though I don't remember all the rules of grammar. However, the first one sounds strange. The last two are good choices in my opinion. If I had to to choose one, I would choose the second option.

Answer (score 1):

An easy rule to follow is to remember that when *off* is used as a preposition (a word that defines the relationship between two nouns), *off of* can almost always be shortened to just *off*.

Therefore the best option for us here is the third one :)